# Not able to display the value from Json response

Tags: angularjs, jersey

I am trying to get a json web response from jersey web service using hibernate.The values are returned from database as i checked in the console.The problem is that when i try to print that in the angular like this

```html
<h1>Welcome to Hibernate Jersey Angular CMS</h1>
 <div id='err'></div>
 <a href="add.html" class='btn btn-success'>New Article</a>
 <p>
 <div>
  <table id='blogList' class="table table-bordered" ng-controller='MyController'>
   <tr>
    <th>Latest Articles</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat='elem in data'>
    <td>{{elem.id}}</td>
    <td><a class='btn btn-warning' href="modify.html?id={{elem.id}}">Modify</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>


</body>
<script src='javascripts/jquery2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='javascripts/bootstrap3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='javascripts/angular1.2.19/angular.js'></script>
<script src='javascripts/json/json2.js'></script>
<script>
 function MyController($scope, $http) {
  //$scope.data = [{title: 'welcome hello'},{title: 'great testing'}];

  $http.get("webapi/blog/list", {}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   $scope.data = data;
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   alert("error");
  })
 }
</script>

</html>
```

the value is not displayed.It is displayed blank like this 
[image]

I know i am getting proper response as the number of rows min the image is same as the number of entries in the table.This is my code for hibernate

```html
public List<Love> getAllLeaves() {
  Session session = HibernateTest.getSession();

  String hql = "from Love";
  Query qry = session.createQuery(hql);
  List<Love> list = qry.list();
  Iterator i=list.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext())
  {
   Love l=(Love) i.next();
   //System.out.println("staretd");
  }
  

  session.close();
  return list;
 }
```

and the jersey code

```html
@GET
 @Path("list")
 @Produces({ "application/json" })
 public List<Love> list() {
  List l= new LeaveDao().getAllLeaves();
  Iterator i=l.iterator();
  while(i.hasNext())
  {
   Love m=(Love)i.next();
   System.out.println(m.getLove());
  }
  
  return l;
 }
```

and bean class

```html
package com.king.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
public class Love {
 public Love(String Love) {
  
  this.id = Love;
 }
 
 public Love()
 {}

 public String getLove() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setLove(String Love) {
  this.id = Love;
 }

 @Id
 @QueryParam("id")
 private String id;

}
```

added network response

[image]

Comment: So, what is the JSON you're getting in the browser? And why are you still using angular 1.2.19, when the current version is 1.6.x?

Comment: have you added directive ng-app ?

Comment: How to see JSON i am getting in browser ? and i am just trying out a tutorial in which they used the same.I will update it to newer version and use

Comment: Open the browser dev tools (F12 on Windows/Linux, Cmd-Alt-i on macOS), click the network panel, then inspect what you get in the response of your request.

Comment: yes i have added it

Comment: i have attached the screenshot.i dont know if thats what you meant

Comment: that's the right panel. But you now need to use your application (or just refresh the page, if that's when the AJAX request is sent), find the problematic AJAX request in the list, click on it, and inspect the response body. My guess is that the request isn't even sent, because you're defining a controller as it could be done when angular was in version 1.0. Use the latest version, and read the angular documentation to understand how you define a controller.

Comment: uhh fixed it.Thanks a lot mate.It was giving the response [{love: "100"}, {love: "200"}, {love: "100"}, {love: "200"}, {love: ",manwndlj"}, {love: "kjashsjkd"},…] and i was using id instead of love .(Still dont know why it is giving love as the response as the column name is id).But fixed the issue for now .Thank you